# Is zero shutter count normal for a new camera?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, shutter-actuations

I just bought a new Nikon D7000 to gift to someone, as always, I tested its shutter count using Exif info and to my surprise it had zero shutter counts, and it seems my test photo was its first.

When I got my own Nikon a year ago, it had about 20 shots, also I heard from many people that it's normal for new cameras to have up to 50 shutter count...

But is having ZERO shutter count normal?! shouldn't they test the camera at factory or by the importer?

Comment: if you ever buy me a present, please don't open it and use it first ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They don't test every unit. It isn't necessary. They test *some* units. Having a shutter count of zero is perfectly normal and not a concern.

I have read anecdotal evidence that people who have owned dozens of DSLR cameras have always received cameras that have a shutter count of zero. I believe it to be few and far between that people receive units that have shutter counts above zero. This is a small sample just based on my forum browsing, but I have seen it mentioned more then once.

This previous question has some debate around *how many* actuations would be considered typical factory testing - [Why does my new camera appear to have over 3000 photos taken already?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10478/why-does-my-new-camera-appear-to-have-over-3000-photos-taken-already/14578#14578)

Keep in mind that a brand new camera that has 25 shutter activation's from testing at the factory, only accounts for .05% of a standard entry level DSLR lifespan(50,000+). More detail can be found in this question: [How many actuations are "too many actuations"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/how-many-actuations-are-too-many-actuations)

Comment: I think if the factory has tested the camera it will still reset the shutter count to zero before packing it up. those that received a shutter count above zero might be the shops allowing the customer to test it first else its a customer who tested it without the shop assistant knowledge.

Comment: It is also more likely that shutter counts above zero are returned items sold again, rather than anything like factory testing or customer trials at a store.

Comment: _red anecdotal evidence_. What about blue? ;)

Comment: @BBking - I'm not sure on blue, I only looked into red.

Answer (score 4):

Having said that too, doesn't mean that it hasn't been tested.

They'll have test jigs to test only the shutter. They calibrate the mirror box and various other things.

It also isn't unlikely that the mainboards are flashed with firmware and a factory reset before assembly while a select few are tested with jigs too.

The reason they mention that is probably to cover themselves using it, or there may have been testing before they received it.

All in all, it's not unusual to have counts 50 and below to 0.

Maybe question it if there is over 100.