# Is my camera used (Shutter count 347)?

Tags: shutter, olympus

I've just purchased a new Olympus E-M1 Mark II from Jessops as Brand New.

It's my first semi-expensive camera so I'm looking for opinions. At the moment there is a promotion that gives you cashback when you purchase this camera, as with all my products I'll register the warranty as soon as I receive it, did the same with the cashback.

In this case I decided to check the shutter actuation's as recommended by a friend but slipped my mind until I've submitted the warranty etc.

The MS: 347

Have spoken to Jessops and they say there is nothing they can do (In terms of a refund or replacement) as I've registered the product and can only offer me £15 for the trouble.

So my question's are:

- Is this normal?
- If it isn't, how much should I be asking for back? (Body was £1400).

Thank you all.

Comment: Related: [How many Shutter Clicks on a New Camera considered normal?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93245/how-many-shutter-clicks-on-a-new-camera-considered-normal)

Answer (score 0):

Generally even brand new cameras have some actuations from the testing at the factory but 300 seems excessive. I'm not sure what the approximate shutter count for an Olympus camera should be from just factory testing but I would expect it to be in the neighborhood of ~100. 
That said 300 shutter actuations is nothing for your camera and if you test it thoroughly and find no issues such as dead pixels or dust on the sensor then I wouldn't worry too much. Sometimes resellers check out the camera themselves and while that's not okay, they're usually careful and you should be okay in the case you can't return your camera.

Comment: Why is that "not okay"? Wouldn't you rather buy a camera that someone has recently confirmed to be in good working order?

Comment: I feel it takes away from the feeling of newness from the camera. The factory QC is done in a clean room environment whereas you have no idea what the conditions were when the camera was checked out by a reseller.

Comment: Okay. I can see that perspective, but I would encourage you to let it go. Cameras are tools meant to be used, not museum pieces. :)

Comment: I believe that a 100% and I'm currently using a used camera myself, with no gripes. I was just talking from the owners perspective who is worried that 300 shutter actuations might be a lot.